# Copying git repo after cloning it to local PC to a different folder

Tags: git, github, copy, clone

I am fairly new. So I have already cloned a repo from git hub! Copying this file and pasting it in a different folder and making changes there. Will it affect my original repo?

Comment: No. In most cases the metadata are stored in `.git` under the repository folder. The new directory and the original directory have their own `.git`. `.git` can be shared, but in your case it does not work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to clone your project in a directory.

```
git clone <url>
```

then do your changes.

and finally do these steps to push your changes.

```
git add * 
git commit -m "some comments about changes"
git push origin master
```

during the process git might ask for some credential